# What is { xyz } = Object, where Object have xyz as property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, object, ecmascript-6

What is { XYZ } = Object called ? where Object have xyz as property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called the [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), and it's used to extract object properties or array elements. Here's an example:

```js
 

const object = { xyz: "abc" };
let { xyz } = object;
console.log(xyz);
```

The above defines an object with a property called `xyz`. It then saves the value of that property to a variable named `xyz`. It's essentially shorthand for doing this in ES5 (because destructuring was introduced in ES6):

```js
 

var object = { xyz: "abc" };
var xyz = object.xyz;
console.log(xyz);
```

You can also rename the destructured variable:

```js
 

const object = { xyz: "abc" };
const { xyz: letters } = object;
console.log(letters);
```

Just as you would the variable:

```js
 

var object = { xyz: "abc" };
var letters = object.xyz;
console.log(letters);
```

It also works with functions:

```js
 

const logName = ({ name }) => console.log(name);
const john = { age: 42, name: "Mr. Doe" };
logName(john);
```

Which is the ES6 equivalent of:

```js
 

function logName(person) {
var name = person.name;
console.log(name);
}
var john = { age: 42, name: "Mr. Doe" };
logName(john);
```

Answer (score 0):

The term you are looking for is 'destructuring assignment'.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 0):

It's called Destructuring assignment https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment